# HTML: How do you make a horizontal Navigation Bar have drop down menus?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, navigationbar

I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS coding, but I'm currently learning and developing a website. However, I'm sort of stuck on the process of my navigation bar. I managed to get a navigation bar to work, a horizontal one, with a working background image. The one thing I do have trouble with is having my navigation bar have drop down menus, like this: http://maxcdn.webappers.com/img/2008/10/free-css-drop-down-menu.png. Except without the extra sub-menus. Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="">home</a></li>
<li><a href="">blank</a></li>
<li><a href="">about</a></li>
<li><a href="">site</a></li>
<li><a href="">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div style="z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%">
<img src="unknown.jpg" style='width:100%;height:100%'/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
    background-color: #8AD9FF;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}
#menu li { 
display: inline; 
padding: 20px; 
}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00F;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #F90;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Sorry if the question is relatively easy to answer, but I'm having trouble. I'm not sure how to change my HTML code into a code where visitors can hover their mouse over, for example, contact and they'll have the option to pick either Administrator or Other. Thank you.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define the onmouseover event of the relevant elements and then, using some Javascript, append new elements somewhere in your menu div (or trigger their visibility). Not the easiest thing to start with for a beginner !